# Ошибка: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ...

Tags: android, java

Пишу программу под операционную систему Android. Требуется занести list[i] в отдельный массив, но при запуске эмулятора выбивает ошибку... в чем может быть проблема?

```
private void search(File aDirectory, List res, int objectType)
{    
    File[]list = aDirectory.listFiles();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {

        if (list[i].isDirectory()) {
            if (objectType != FILES && accept(list[i].getName())) {
                directoriesNumber++;
            }
            search(list[i], res, objectType);
        }

        else {    
            if (objectType != DIRECTORIES && accept(list[i].getName())) {
                filesNumber++;
                totalLength += list[i].length();
                newlist[z] = list[i];        // запись в новый массив
                z++;
            }
        }
    }
```

> `04-21 12:03:49.930: D/AndroidRuntime(1330): Shutting down VM
> 04-21 12:03:49.930: W/dalvikvm(1330): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
> 04-21 12:03:49.960: E/AndroidRuntime(1330): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> 04-21 12:03:49.960: E/AndroidRuntime(1330): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{jj.kk/jj.kk.HhhActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
> 04-21 12:03:49.960: E/AndroidRuntime(1330):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
> 04-21 12:03:49.960: E/AndroidRuntime(1330):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
> 04-21 12:03:49.960: E/AndroidRuntime(1330):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
> 04-21 12:03:49.960: E/AndroidRuntime(1330):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
> 04-21 12:03:49.960: E/AndroidRuntime(1330):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> 04-21 12:03:49.960: E/AndroidRuntime(1330):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
> 04-21 12:03:49.960: E/AndroidRuntime(1330):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
> 04-21 12:03:49.960: E/AndroidRuntime(1330):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
> 04-21 12:03:49.960: E/AndroidRuntime(1330):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
> 04-21 12:03:49.960: E/AndroidRuntime(1330):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
> 04-21 12:03:49.960: E/AndroidRuntime(1330):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
> 04-21 12:03:49.960: E/AndroidRuntime(1330):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
> 04-21 12:03:49.960: E/AndroidRuntime(1330): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
> 04-21 12:03:49.960: E/AndroidRuntime(1330):     at jj.kk.HhhActivity.search(HhhActivity.java:90)
> 04-21 12:03:49.960: E/AndroidRuntime(1330):     at jj.kk.HhhActivity.browseTo(HhhActivity.java:104)
> 04-21 12:03:49.960: E/AndroidRuntime(1330):     at jj.kk.HhhActivity.onCreate(HhhActivity.java:47)
> 04-21 12:03:49.960: E/AndroidRuntime(1330):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
> 04-21 12:03:49.960: E/AndroidRuntime(1330):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
> 04-21 12:03:49.960: E/AndroidRuntime(1330):     ... 11 more`

Comment: Что за ошибка то?

Comment: Sorry!
The application xXx has stoped unexpectedly.Please try again....

Comment: Проблема появляется после того, как я пытаюсь записать все в новый массив ...

Comment: не информативно

Comment: Нужно просмотреть количество файлов в директории, а также во всех вложенных в нее директориях, в list[i] идет запись всех найденных файлов. `if(list[i].isDirectory())` - здесь если нашлась директория, то поиск начинается во вложенной директории. `search(list[i], res, objectType);` то есть опять вызывается search.
Если нашелся файл, то работает else . И записываю в массив, где будут храниться все мои файлы `newlist[z]=list[i];` z - глобальная переменная. `private void search(File aDirectory,List res ,int objectType)` вызывается сама в себе несколько раз, поэтому в `list[i]` творится чепуха.

Comment: я про ошибку, кинь лог с IDE, а не то что андроид пишет

Comment: VioLet, спасибо... ошибку нашел =)
теперь работает ...
Просто размер массиву newlist не задал .. поэтому фигня была...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я вижу строчку "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException". В Java ни в зуб ногой, но что-то мне подсказывает, что у вас появляется пустой указатель - за  границы массива выходит, например (проверьте `z` - может он больше чем размер `newlist` или еще чего).

Answer (score 0):

где проверка на выход за границы массива?

java.lang.NullPointerException - это значит, что у вас непроинициализирована переменная, я советую провести **дебаг** в этом месте.